# jBPM restricting workspaces

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jbpm

I am just curious to know how to hide/restrict workspaces in jBPM. Currently, a user is able to see all the workspaces available on the server.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot grant permissions directly to users but can grant them to groups (where the user belongs to).

In Business Central, Admin > Groups, you can tune the permissions per space:

[image]

Comment: Hello, @Gonzalo Muñoz Thank you for your response.